# Plot each value of an array in separate plots

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib, plot

I would like to plot each value of a random array, each in a different plot. The values in the arrays represent the length of a line, so if I have [ 2, 6, 9] I want three plots, each with a horizontal line of length 2, 6 and 9. Also, I want that each value is linked with a color.

I did this, but maybe I thought it in the wrong way and can be much simpler. Any help?

```
line_lengths = np.random.randint(0, 10 ,9)
y= 1
#Assign colors to the values in line_lengths
colors = plt.cm.rainbow(np.linspace(0, 1, len(line_lengths)))
c = [colors[val] for val in line_lengths]


print(line_lengths)
#Plot each value of line_lengths in a single plot
for  line_length, color in zip( line_lengths, c):
    plt.plot(xmin=0, xmax=line_length, colors=color)
```

Answer (score 0):

I used subplots:

```
line_lengths = np.random.randint(0, 9 ,9)
y= 1
#Assign colors to the values in line_lengths
colors = plt.cm.rainbow(np.linspace(0, 1, len(line_lengths)))
c = [colors[val] for val in line_lengths]

print(line_lengths)
fig, axes = plt.subplots(3, 3, figsize=(7.2, 7.2))
axes = axes.ravel()
#Plot each value of line_lengths in a single plot
for i, (line_length, color) in enumerate(zip( line_lengths, c)):
    axes[i].plot([0, line_length], [y*i, y*i], color=color)
    axes[i].set_xlim(-1, 10)
```

[image]

Comment: Sort of. I want each line in a separate plot. So in the end I should obtain 9 plots.

Answer (score 0):

When you say a plot per value do you mean a line like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


line_lengths = np.random.randint(0, 10 ,9)

print(line_lengths)

#Assign colors to the values in line_lengths
colors = plt.cm.rainbow(np.linspace(0, 1, len(line_lengths)))
c = [colors[val-1] for val in line_lengths]

plt.figure(1)

#Plot each value of line_lengths in a single plot
for i in range(0,len(line_lengths),1):
    x_val=range(0,line_lengths[i]+1,1)
    y_val=[i]*(line_lengths[i]+1)
    color_val=c[i]
    plt.plot(x_val,y_val,color=color_val)


plt.show()
```

Result:
[image]

Or a subplot by value:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


line_lengths = np.random.randint(0, 10 ,9)

print(line_lengths)

#Assign colors to the values in line_lengths
colors = plt.cm.rainbow(np.linspace(0, 1, len(line_lengths)))
c = [colors[val-1] for val in line_lengths]


plt.figure(1)

#Plot each value of line_lengths in a single plot
for i in range(0,len(line_lengths),1):
    subplot_pos=int(f"{len(line_lengths)}{1}{i+1}")
    ax=plt.subplot(subplot_pos)
    x_val=range(0,line_lengths[i]+1,1)
    y_val=[1]*(line_lengths[i]+1)
    color_val=c[i]
    plt.plot(x_val,y_val,color=color_val)
    plt.xlim(0, 9)
    #hide the x and labels and ticks
    if i !=len(line_lengths)-1:
        plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), visible=False)
        ax.set_xticks([])
    plt.setp(ax.get_yticklabels(), visible=False)
    ax.set_yticks([])

plt.show()
```

[image]